# Word 2013: Unable to remove the last page

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-word-2013

I'm currently running word 2013 on windows. I have a word document that contains three pages. I did not create that document nor did I change the page sizes. When I received the document from my college, the size of the first two pages was set to "A4" and the last page was set to "letter". I wanted to remove the last page so tried the following methods:

> **ATTEMPT 1:** Enabling paragraph marks. highlighting the paragraph marks on the last pages and then deleting them.
>   **Result:** Doesn't work. The paragraph marks dont get deleted.
>    **ATTEMPT 2:** Clicking on the thumbnail of the last page in the navigation pane and hitting delete.
>   **Result:** Doesn't work. Hitting the delete button does nothing.

Is there any other way I can delete the last page. I've linked the doc file Im dealing with [here](https://1drv.ms/w/s!ApJrNqcv2bOEiyFNmGNxHkIdyQ8Y)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to remove the blank page by using the following sequence:

- Control-End to move to end of page.
- Shift-Control-Left-Arrow (once) to
  highlight Section Break.
- Delete removes the page.

Comment: It's working thanks. but when the last page gets deleted, the second page's size gets converted from A4 to letter. In general when the last page having a letter size gets deleted the second last page having A4 size gets converted to letter and becomes the last page. If I try to change it back to A4 it shows an error message stating something like "the boundry is out of range for the new size". I think it's format and layout issue. I'll try to solve it.

Comment: This is because you have different page sizes for different sections. Try putting the cursor at the very end of your document. Then go to `Layout -> Page Setup -> `Layout` and select "Continuous" for your section start. It should prevent your section break from forcing a new page.